# Android: How to have a GridView filled with 2 adapters

Tags: android, gridview

How can I use two adapters on one GridView?

So I am trying to create a GridView, and fill it with two different types of info, so I tried using to adapters to do so, such as:

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);


    ArrayList<Grids> cellArray = new ArrayList<>();
    GridAdapter cellAdapter = new GridAdapter(this.getActivity(), cellArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(cellAdapter);

    Grids arrayOfCells[] = new Grids[grid];

    for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfCells.length; j++) {
        arrayOfCells[j] = new Grids(false);
        cellAdapter.add(arrayOfCells[j]);
    }

    ArrayList<Time> arrayOfTime = new ArrayList<>();
    timeAdapter adapter = new timeAdapter(this.getActivity(), arrayOfTime);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    Time arrayGrid[] = new Time[grid];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayGrid.length; i++) {
        arrayGrid[i] = new Time(arrayOfHours[i], arrayOfPeriod[i]);
        adapter.add(arrayGrid[i]);
    }
```

However, when I do so, only the second one is added to the gridView. So how would I go about doing this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set one Adapter instance on GridView. When you set the second adapter it's replacing the first adapter.

To solve this, you need to combine both data sources and put them inside of a single Adapter. One way to do it would be to create an ArrayList and add Grids and Time objects to it:

```
    ArrayList<Object> adapterData = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfCells.length; j++) {
        adapterData.add(new Grids(false));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayGrid.length; i++) {
        adapterData.add(new Time(arrayOfHours[i], arrayOfPeriod[i]));
    }

    TimeOrGridsAdapter adapter = new TimeOrGridsAdapter(this.getActivity(), adapterData);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note that inside of this new TimeOrGridsAdapter, you'll need to figure out whether the Object is a Time OR a Grids object and then create the view accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! What would I do for "TimeOrGridsAdapter"? Do you just mean either or, or do I need to create a new adapter?